# Command failed with exit code 1... Errors because spaces in path

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I need help with Multi-Device Hybrid Apps

I currently get the following error when attempting to run a hybrid app using the new cordova ctp for Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

C:\Users\Juan David.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 1

And...

El comando ""C:\Users\Juan David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android -- configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "VisualStudioOnlineExplorer"" salió con el código 8.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have spaces in your project path. This is a [known sssue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722404.aspx) with the Cordova platform ([issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6256](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6256)).

The current workaround is to have a user on the machine without spaces in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it using the command line, you may escape the spaces by using the caret (^) symbol.